# Maven reuse in poms

Tags: maven-2, import, reusability

In our Maven project, we are trying the following directory structure (with about 80 projects total, only a few are shown so that you get the idea):

```
myappli      (pom)
-- module1       (pom)
--|-- utils    (pom)
--|-- ejb       (pom)
--|--|-- myappli-module1-a-ejb    (jar)
--|--|-- myappli-module1-b-ejb    (jar)
--|-- war       (pom)
--|-- applet       (pom)
...
-- module6       (pom)
--|-- utils       (pom)
--|-- ejb       (pom)
--|--|-- myappli-module6-c-ejb    (jar)
--|-- war       (pom)
--|-- applet       (pom)
```

> Note: This is a *flat* structure for Maven, as all non-leaf projects have a `packaging` value of "pom". (cf BetterBuildsWithMaven book).

We define the dependency versions in "`dependencyManagement`", in the "`myappli`" pom. This works fine.

**Our problem is with the reuse of the dependencies themselves**.
For example, the ejb dependencies are common to all ejb projects (by design).
We don't want to cut'n-paste, and maintain all that with each change!

We were thinking to use some "**import notion**" for the ejb dependencies, and define our ejb dependencies once at the application level. Our unsuccessful attempts were:

- The Maven "`parent pom`" notion would be fine, but it is already used by the modules, so it is not available for our requirement.
- No import facility found in Maven (except for dependencyManagement)
- XML entity definition is not recognized. We tried a pom like the following, and got the error
  "`Reason: Parse error reading POM. Reason: could not resolve entity named 'ejbDependencies'`":

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
  `<!DOCTYPE project [`
    `<!ENTITY ejbDependencies SYSTEM "./ejbDependencies.txt">`
  `]>`
  `<project ...`
  ...
  `&ejbDependencies;`
  ...

---

**Edited** : I am trying the solution suggested by Robert, but something is wrong.

When I compile my ejb project, it doesn't find the dependencies themselves. I get an error when compiling (mvn compile), saying the javax.ejb package is missing.

> Note: I did run "mvn install" on the dependencies project before.

This is my configuration :

```
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproj-maven-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>${myproj-version}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

---------------------------------
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj-identite-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproj-identite-metier</artifactId>
  <name>SNR IDENTITE METIER</name>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproj-maven-ejb</artifactId>
      <version>${myproj-version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

I don't know if it changes something, but we have a hierarchy that relates the two poms.
We have a strict Maven structure, where each directory declares all subdirectories as maven modules, and each subdirectory declares the parent as a maven parent.
And the common parent directory is part of this structure.

```
+---maven
|   \---ejb
+---identite
|   +---ejb
|   |   \---SNR_IDENTITE_METIER
```

---

**Edited**:

The answer given by reef seem correct. It is impossible to do with Maven, because our dependency are provided, and therefore not transitive :-(

> We really have many problems with setup up Maven. So many little things just don't work. Today I found out that the site target cannot handle properties, that we are using for version numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your imported dependencies have a *provided* scope?
Indeed this scope is not transitive (see Maven [Dependency Scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)).

This could be the reason of the non-replacement.

Answer (score 9):

You can use *pom dependencies* to import dependencies into arbitrary projects.

A pom project can look similar to:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-deps</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernateAnnotationsVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And is imported as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-deps</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

See [Maven, the definitive guide -  Grouping Dependencies](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)  for details.

Comment: +1 for an answer that looks perfect. I'm trying it right now. (note : a few minutes ago, you also edited my "typo" in another answer ;-) )

Comment: I tried this. I run "mvn install" on the dependencies project. Then I compile my ejb project, it doesn't find the dependencies themselves.

Comment: To check, I run a help:effective-pom. It doesn't replace the dependency by the set of dependencies. It this normal? How could I check where I am wrong?

Comment: I can't speak for your specific scenario, but I would try to either replicate it with a very simple project or find a working example somewhere else.